# Change the footer in word doc using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

i have a .docx template with string that i want to replace by another one (like serialNumber, date, author, etc). I want to use excel for that.

```
    Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
    Set MaFeuille = Sheets("Information")

    Dim file As String
    file = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "nomfichier.docx"

    Dim word_app As Object
    Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With word_app
        .Visible = True
        .WindowState = 1 'value for wdWindowStateMaximize
    End With

    Dim word_fichier As Object
    
    Set word_fichier = word_app.Documents.Open(file)
    With word_fichier.Range.Find
        .Text = "blabla"
        .Replacement.Text = "coucou"
        .Execute Replace:=2
    End With
```

It's working but not in the header/footer. So i red the documentation about Header/Footer (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.headersfooters), so just for trying i typed the exemple :

```
    With word_fichier.Sections(1)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Header goes here"
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Footer goes here"
    End With
```

But i have a 5941 error.

Comment: Does adding `Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks` to the start of the macro fix it?

Comment: Do you have "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" added to References under tools? I tried your code and when this was added, it worked.

Comment: Its most likely that you still don't have a reference to Word in your project so wdHeaderFooterPrimary is undefined and therefore zero.  Please adopt the following strategy.1. Put Option Explicit at the start of every Module/Class/Form.  2. If you are creating late bound object you **must** manually define any constants or enumeration used in the object model of the late bound object.  3. Before running any code do a Debug.Compile Project, and deal with any errors that get flagged.  4. Once you get a clean compile, look at the rubberduck inspections and resolve those that need to be addressed.

Comment: @freeflow i cant add rubberduck on my company computer :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Míša Charvátová, i added "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" and it's working.

Edit (better answer) :

> Do you have "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" added to References under tools? I tried your code and when this was added, it worked

Comment: In addition to doing that you should also declare your variables with the correct datatypes, i.e.: `Dim word_app As Word.Application` and `Dim word_fichier As Word.Document` There is no benefit to using late binding when working across the Office applications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).